# match pattern and return only the value i want with regex and php

Tags: php, regex

I have a collection of string. Now i want to return the specific value from that string with possibly Regex or somehow. I don't know much of regex how to do this things so please help me guy's. Thank You

**here is an example of a string:**

2017-04-20T17:00:19+00:00

yt:video:**eaLKqoB9Fu0**
  eaLKqoB9Fu0
  UC8butISFwT-Wl7EV0hUK0BQ

there could be extra content so we have to leave them.

2017-04-17T17:59:04+00:00
  2017-04-25T20:06:02+00:00

there could be extra content so we have to leave them.

yt:video:**z_mSgK-6pOQ**
  z_mSgK-6pOQ
  UC8butISFwT-Wl7EV0hUK0BQ

2017-04-18T15:56:51+00:00
  2017-04-25T19:56:06+00:00

there could be extra content so we have to leave them.
 there could be extra content so we have to leave them.

yt:video:**0fy9TCcX8Uc**
  0fy9TCcX8Uc
  UC8butISFwT-Wl7EV0hUK0BQ

// There could be huge content like this so we need only id's after **yt:video:**

**I want values as array with specific value from that string**

[eaLKqoB9Fu0, z_mSgK-6pOQ, 0fy9TCcX8Uc]   // and so on like this

I hope you guys understood what actually I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/783704)

**Regex:** `/yt:video:\K[^\s]+/`

> **1.** `/yt:video:\K/` This part will match `yt:video:` and `\K` will reset current match.
>
> **2.** `[^\s]+` this will match all till not a `space`

**PHP code**

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string='2017-04-20T17:00:19+00:00

yt:video:eaLKqoB9Fu0 eaLKqoB9Fu0 UC8butISFwT-Wl7EV0hUK0BQ

there could be extra content so we have to leave them.

2017-04-17T17:59:04+00:00 2017-04-25T20:06:02+00:00

there could be extra content so we have to leave them.

yt:video:z_mSgK-6pOQ z_mSgK-6pOQ UC8butISFwT-Wl7EV0hUK0BQ

2017-04-18T15:56:51+00:00 2017-04-25T19:56:06+00:00

there could be extra content so we have to leave them. there could be extra content so we have to leave them.

yt:video:0fy9TCcX8Uc 0fy9TCcX8Uc UC8butISFwT-Wl7EV0hUK0BQ';

preg_match_all("/yt:video:\K[^\s]+/",$string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => eaLKqoB9Fu0
            [1] => z_mSgK-6pOQ
            [2] => 0fy9TCcX8Uc
        )

)
```

Comment: Can you please give an explanation of this Regex ?

Comment: and also how can i learn regex efficiently, any suggestion appreciated :)

Comment: @Smalldeveloper I have added explanation in my post.. you can check it.